# Wait chain traversal equivalent on Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, debugging

How can one have functionality similar to Windows [wait chain traversal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681622(v=vs.85).aspx) on a Linux-based system? More generally, how can one view the resources/objects for which threads are waiting?